# lisp - String to struct or list

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp

I have a problem with common lisp.

I want to pass a string to a function
and want that this strings become a structure.
I can't use external library.

For example with this input:

```
(testfu "ftp/http.ok:3345")
```

This is the struct:

```
(defstruct test-struct
    scheme 
    part
    ans     
port)
```

I want this result:

> scheme: "ftp" part: "http" ans "ok" port "3345"

How can I do the testfu ?

here my bad try :(

```
(defun testfu (x) 
(setq ur1 (make-test-struct :scheme frist x :host second x)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to parse the data out of the string in order that you might use it for your strut. Lisp won't do that magically.

[Split Sequence](http://www.cliki.net/SPLIT-SEQUENCE) is a good library for doing that

If you don't want a library, then some code to get you on the correct track. This will tokenize string based on a predicate function fn ( which returns true when a character is a delimiter and false otherwise )

```
(defun split-by-fn (fn string)
  (let* ((STARTING 0)
         (TOKEN 1)
         (DELIM 2)
         (state STARTING)
         (a-token "")
         (the-list '())
         (str-length (length string)))
    (dotimes (i str-length)
      (if (funcall fn (char string i))
          (progn
            (if (eq state TOKEN)
                (progn
                  (setq the-list (cons a-token the-list))
                  (setq a-token "")))
            (setq state DELIM))
        (progn
          (setq a-token
                (concatenate 'string a-token (string (char string i))))
          (setq state TOKEN))))
    (if (eq state TOKEN)
        (setq the-list (cons a-token the-list)))
    (setq the-list (reverse the-list))))
```

I don't usually write code for people but here is an example parser, it's not the most lisp-y, there are better ways of doing this, but it works.

```
(defun parser ( string )
  (labels ((set-field (state struct token)
            (let ((SCHEME 0)
                  (PART   1)
                  (ANS    2)
                  (PORT   3))
            (cond ((= state SCHEME) 
                    (setf (example-struct-SCHEME struct) token))
                  ((= state PART)  
                    (setf (example-struct-PART struct) token))
                  ((= state ANS)  
                    (setf (example-struct-ANS struct) token))
                  ((= state PORT)  
                    (setf (example-struct-PORT struct) token))))))
    (let ((state  0)
          (token "")
          (check 0)
          (a-list '())
          (struct (make-example-struct)))
      (loop for char across string do
        (progn
          (setq check (position char "/.:"))
          (if check
            (progn
              (set-field state struct token)
              (setq token "")
              (setq state (+ check 1)))
            (setq token (concatenate 'string token (string char))))))
      (progn
        (if (/= 0 (length token))
          (set-field state struct token))
          struct))))
```

Comment: thnks :) but if dont want in order ?
eg : 
val port is the values following the charather ":" 
can i scann the string? :)

Comment: you could build a parser, that instead if tokenizes on fn runs a cond block that does things based on the value of the char.

Comment: thnks for code but i can implement in my function ? 
i dont understand how i can use it :(

Comment: an example ? :( please help me @Mimisbrunnr

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend using a regex to parse this. Using CL-PPCRE which is the Common Lisp regex library, the code would look like this:

```
(defun testfu (x)
  (multiple-value-bind (result values)
      (ppcre:scan-to-strings "^([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)\\.([a-z]+):([0-9]+)$" x)
    (unless result
      (error "String ~s is not valid" x))
    (make-test-struct :scheme (aref values 0)
                      :part (aref values 1)
                      :ans (aref values 2)
                      :port (aref values 3))))
```

Note that you probably would have to adjust the regex to better represent the actual format of the input string, in particular if any of the fields are optional.

Comment: thnks :) 
there is way without an external libary ? :)

Comment: There is no regex library as part of the Common Lisp specification if that's what you're asking. That shouldn't stop you from using it though, as CL-PPCRE works with all CL implementations that I know of. Installing it with Quicklisp is very easy.